# How do I access property of fellow nested object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, javascript-objects

So, I tried to initialize a variable using this snippet of code,

```
    var foo = {bar: {baz: 3}, qux: {fooAgain: foo.bar.baz + 5}}
```

But I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read  property  'bar' of undefined`

How would I access property `baz` from `qux`?

Comment: You cannot in an object literal declaration. There is nothing to access yet when `fooAgain` is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer in response to your comment:

```
var bar = {baz: 3};
var foo = {bar: bar, qux: {fooAgain: bar.baz + 5}};
```

This way you first create bar variable and then create your foo variable using it.

**Explaination**: 
Your original code did not work because you were trying to access property bar of foo object before the foo object was actually initialized.

Comment: That is not what I intended. I want a single variable with the following fields, `bar` and `qux`. `bar` is an object itself with a single field, `baz`, intialized to 3. And `qux` is an object too with a single field, `fooAgain`, that I want to initialize to 5 plus `baz`. What I would like to know is how to access `baz` from within `fooAgain`.

Comment: I guess this would be the only possible way to do it.